# UIScrollView - Add Subview so that it's centered Horizontal and Vertical

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview

How do I add, in code, a UIImageView to a UIScrollView so that it appears in the center.

The scroll view fills a large area, the UIImage view is about 40% the size on average.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about imageView.center = scrollView.center

Answer (score 1):

What about something around the lines of...

```
int size = 20;

UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];

UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((scrollView.center.x - (size / 2)), (scrollView.center.y - (size / 2)), size, size)];

[scrollView addSubview:imageView];
```